# How to score difference between estimates and real values from simulated data

Tags: r, estimation, simulation

I'm attempting to do some power calulations based on simulated choice data and I need some pointers on how to score the difference between the estimates derived from my simulated data, and the true values of the underlying parameters which generated the simulated data.

I'm doing something like the following in R:

```
realPars <- c( 0.65, -1.05, -1.05, -1.39)
choiceNum <- 150

mkChoice <- function(pars,N){
    # Makes N choices which are determined by 'pars'
}

simDat <- mkChoice(realPars ,N)

estFun <- function(par,data){
    # Function to pass into optim, basically 'mkChoice' in reverse
}

init <- c(0.5, -1, -1, -1)
fit <- optim(par=init, fn=estFun, method="BFGS", hessian=T)

# Get the inverse of the Hessian
fisher <- solve(fit$hessian)
# Get the square root of it
se <- sqrt(diag(fisher))

res <- data.frame( est=fit$par , se=se , real=realPars )

print(res)

   real        est         se
1  0.60  0.5479614 0.05002214 
2 -1.05 -1.0253736 0.25474913 
3 -1.05 -1.1925617 0.12775304 
4 -1.39 -1.5724553 0.44499488
```

I believe I've calculated the standard errors correctly, but please let me know if I'm wrong.

Since this process is for power calculations, I ultimately want to be able to judge the difference between the estimates and the real values, weighted in some way by the standard error of the estimates. Thus, estimates that are closer should get a "better" score, but if the standard error is high, this score should be diminished.

Is there a standard way to do this?

I was thinking along the lines of `(real - est)^2 * se`, does this make sense?